# ListViewAnimations, не компилируется проект

Tags: android, listview

Пытаюсь включить в свой проект `ListViewAnimations`.

1. > https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations/blob/master/README.md
2. > http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/#getting-started
3. > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hgc51aJJfNc

Все, вроде, делаю по инструкции, но проект не компилируется и выдает неведомую мне ошибку:

```
`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/com.nineoldandroids/library/pom.properties
    File1: C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\ListViewAnimations-master\SuckAndroid\app\libs\nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar
    File2: C:\Users\Igor\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.nineoldandroids\library\2.4.0\e9b63380f3a242dbdbf103a2355ad7e43bad17cb\library-2.4.0.jar`
```

Пожалуйста, подскажите как исправить. Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас дублируются какие-то файлы/библиотеки
Попробуйте вот это в `build.gradle` добавить:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```